# How do I get the navigation goal from RVIZ

Tags: navigation, 2d, kinect, ros

In rospy I am able to get the initial pose of my turtlebot using the two statements:

```
rospy.wait_for_message('initialpose', PoseWithCovarianceStamped);
rospy.Subscriber('initialpose', PoseWithCovarianceStamped, self.update_initial_pose);
```

This allows me to get a the initial pose when a user clicks and sets the 2d Pose estimate in RVIZ. My question is threefold

- How do I achieve the same with the 2d Navigation Goal (How do I get it fom RVIZ)?
- What message should I wait for and subscribe to (e.g. with initial pose its 'initialpose')?
- What TYPE of message am I looking for? For example with initialpose I get a PoseWithCovarianceStamped message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never use it, but the answer should be [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack).

```
Topic: move_base_simple/goal
Type: geometry_msgs/PoseStamped
```

So I can imagine it should be something like this:

```
rospy.wait_for_message('move_base_simple/goal', PoseStamped);
rospy.Subscriber('move_base_simple/goal', PoseStamped, self.update_goal);
```

Feel free to explore the huge [navigation package](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) and its tutorials.

Comment: Moreover, you can change the topic name in rviz in the "Tool Properties" panel, in case you don't like the default (you may first have to make it visible in the "Panels" menu).